# Heroku Java Gradle App crashes with Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/reactivex/rxjava3/core/ObservableSource

Tags: java, gradle, heroku

The deploy goes smoothly but when i try to view the page it crashes with

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/reactivex/rxjava3/core/ObservableSource
```

This is the log:

```
2020-06-16T19:51:11.803792+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting

2020-06-16T19:51:14.817284+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java -jar BoardStar.jar 6060`

2020-06-16T19:51:16.771301+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.

2020-06-16T19:51:16.775498+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -XX:+UseContainerSupport -Xmx300m -Xss512k
-XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

2020-06-16T19:51:17.005105+00:00 app[web.1]: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/reactivex/rxjava3/core/ObservableSource

2020-06-16T19:51:17.005428+00:00 app[web.1]: at boardstar.webapp.BoardstarWebApp.<clinit>(BoardstarWebApp.java:31)

2020-06-16T19:51:17.005908+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.ObservableSource

2020-06-16T19:51:17.006060+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)

2020-06-16T19:51:17.006174+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)

2020-06-16T19:51:17.006256+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)

2020-06-16T19:51:17.006348+00:00 app[web.1]: ... 1 more

2020-06-16T19:51:17.069174+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1

2020-06-16T19:51:17.104655+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

2020-06-16T19:51:22.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
```

This is my build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    // Apply the java-library plugin to add support for Java Library
    id 'java-library'
}

sourceCompatibility = '11'

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Main-Class': 'boardstar.webapp.BoardstarWebApp'
        )
    }
}

repositories {
    // Use jcenter for resolving dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    jcenter()
}

task stage(dependsOn: ['build', 'clean'])
build.mustRunAfter clean

task copyLib(type: Copy) {
    from jar.archivePath
    into project.rootDir 
    rename {
        'BoardStar.jar'
    }
}
stage.dependsOn(copyLib)

dependencies {
    // JSON Parser
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'

    // HTTP Async Client
    implementation 'org.asynchttpclient:async-http-client:2.12.1'

    //Reactive Java
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxjava:3.0.3'

    // Javalin
    implementation 'io.javalin:javalin:3.8.0'
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:1.7.30'

    //FreeMarker
    implementation 'org.freemarker:freemarker:2.3.30'

    // Use JUnit test framework
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: See this [heroku project](https://github.com/smac89/robotsjavabackend/tree/aeb44fe2ad828bb76927898570aa4fda24bcaba2) [gradle file](https://github.com/smac89/robotsjavabackend/blob/713cf3e87f927c9685201a01c2800f4075fb2c25/gradle/config/heroku.gradle). My guess is that you are not properly copying all the dependencies to the output folder. The link I shared contains a `stage` task which shows how I usually package dependencies for heroku

Comment: @smac89 Thanks for the help but since im not using SpringBoot im not sure it applies.

Comment: There is nothing specific to `spring` that is done in that stage task. It is simply going to run and copy all the dependencies of your project to a folder specified in the `installDist` task. Should work regardless of what kind of java project you have. **BTW** The `installDist` task comes from either the [`application`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html) plugin or the [`distribution`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/distribution_plugin.html) plugin, both of which come with gradle

Comment: Ah! That last bit helped, added the application plugin. I think my procfile should be changed. I had it like this "web: java -jar BoardStar.jar 6060" because i was copying the jar to the rootdir

Comment: @smac89 your procfile gives me an error ` '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Found a solution by adding this to build.gradle: 
`task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'boardstar.webapp.BoardstarWebApp'
    }
    baseName = 'BoardStar'
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}`